# How to add save button in a form magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, adminhtml

How can I add **save button** as in the container for each form and not one for all forms (as we have in magento by default)? I share with you this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gdvQ.jpg) is what I have.
And I want something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiRQg.jpg)
I get a button without word like 
[image: this]

using this code

```
   $fieldset->addField('yourfield', 'button', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('thorleif')->__('Button Labels'),
    'value' => Mage::helper('thorleif')->__('Button Caption'),
    'name'  => 'yourfield',
    'style' => 'width:64px; height:21px;',
    'class' => 'form-button',
    'onclick' => "setLocation('{$url}')",
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen that always the value in html source code goes empty. So I've read that you have to change `$form->setValues` in your file by `$form->addValues` and it will work.

Comment: THANK YOU!  This is exactly what I was seeing and I had no idea why.  I still don't....but at least my button has a value now!